# Is it necessary to state that $y_i \leq 1$

Tags: probability, notation, linear-programming, game-theory

In a class test for Linear Programming, my professor deducted some marks because I missed the condition $y_i \leq 1$ in the mixed strategy games solution.

$ y_i $ stands for the probability of any step a player can make. My exact statement for $y_i$ was:

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{y_i} = 1 \tag{$y_i \geq 0\ \  \text{ where } \ \  i = 1,2, \cdots, n$}
$$
I kept on saying that since all probabilities are non-zero and summing to $1$, none of them can ever exceed the value $1$ itself. Was I wrong in declaring like that? Or is it wrong to skip mentioning that

$$
0 \leq y_i \leq 1 \tag{$i = 1,2, \cdots, n$}
$$

Comment: Sounds quite reasonable to me.  Are you certain it was your professor who deducted marks and not someone else?

Comment: @ErickWong Yeah, we're having that doubt here too amongst the students :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  In fact, adding the redundant upper bound on the individual variables creates a small complication for the solver.  With the upper bound each $y_i$ has two possible nonbasic values, 0 and 1.